# How to check if the gameObject is active or not

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, input, gameobject

I am making a backpack and I am trying to make it like Minecraft how you just press "E" and it will open and if is already open then they close it. Bty I am using Unity in C#.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(backpackKey) && backpack.activeInHierarchy == false)
{
   backpack.SetActive(true);
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown(backpackKey) && backpack.activeInHierarchy == true)
{
    backpack.SetActive(false);
}
```

Comment: So what's problem in this code ?

Comment: It doesn't work. Every time when I press e to open it, it does nothing. Closing it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Both your if conditions will match:

1. your object is inactive
2. You set it active
3. Now also the second condition matches
4. You set it inactive again

Either use `else if` to make both blocks run **exclusive** or .. actually you could simply do

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(backpackKey))
{
    // I would prefer using "activeSelf"
    // If any parent is inactive your check might always return false even though the object
    // itself is already set to active. Don't know if it has an impact on performance
    // I just find it more convenient here since this is the value changed by "SetActive"
    backpack.SetActive(!backpack.activeSelf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `else` statement:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(backpackKey))
{
  if(backpack.activeInHierarchy == false)
  {
    backpack.SetActive(true);
  } else {
    backpack.SetActive(false);
  }
}
```

In your code, whenever you try to open it then you end up falling into the second condition, now true, and closing it immediately.